# Show source code of HTML element on click

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display the source code of an element on a web page inside a text box when the element is clicked. Is it possible to obtain the source code of an element when the element is clicked (using the `onClick` property), and then display the element inside the text box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it certainly is possible. The following code [is demonstrated here](http://jsfiddle.net/W8YQP/1/), and displays the source code when the text is clicked.

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/W8YQP/2/) with more elements on the page (which are all shown in the text box when clicked.)

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function showSourceCode(toShow){
    sourceCode.value = toShow.innerHTML;
}
</script>

<p onclick = "showSourceCode(this);">
    <b>Show source code on click!</b>
</p>

<input type="text" id = sourceCode></input>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @David Yes, this would be a useful feature to incorporate into a web-based IDE.

Comment: outerHTML would be more appropriate.

Comment: @Gael Hm... can you post an example on jsfiddle to show what you mean by this?

Comment: outerHTML returns also the tag of the element, while innerHTML returns just its content.